# Why did I get -10 reputation for "user removed"?

Tags: support, reputation, user-accounts

In my reputation dropdown, on the top bar, I see -10 reputation for "user was removed". When I click on it, it links to my own profile page.

Why did this happen?

Comment: Don't cry, you've got 2844 rep anyway... And you have probably got atleast 15 rep from this question ;-)

Comment: @wilf reputation doesn't count on meta

Comment: I sort of know.... Otherwise I would have -1000 on other forums etc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [What does “user was removed” mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it) on the main meta. In short, a user who had upvoted one of your answers was deleted, so all their votes were removed as well, so you lost the 10 reputation you'd gotten from their upvote.